# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to use JMockit Coverage

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I am trying to use JMockit's code coverage abilities. Using the JVM parameter

```
-javaagent:jmockit.jar=coverage=.*MyClass.java:html::
```

I am able to run my tests (jmockit.jar and coverage.jar are on the classpath), unfortunately my log file says:

```
Loaded external tool: mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage=.*MyClass.java:html::
Loaded external tool: mockit.integration.junit3.JUnitTestCaseDecorator
Loaded external tool: mockit.integration.junit4.JUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage$OutputFileGenerator.run(CodeCoverage.java:56)
```

...and no coverage file is generated. Has anyone gotten JMockit Coverage to work? If so, any thoughts as to what is causing this error? Thanks...

**Answer**: <s>I needed to add coverage to the bootstrap entries rather than only the user entries (in the Eclipse run configuration)</s>

**Actual Answer** The actual answer is that I was running the test with JUnit 3, but the coverage needs JUnit 4. That fixed things, and I didn't have to add any bootstrap entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running the test with JUnit 3, but the coverage needs JUnit 4. That fixed things, and I didn't have to add any bootstrap entries.

Answer (score 1):

Random guess... Is coverage.jar on the classpath that jmockit uses - it might be a different one?

Comment: Any idea how I can find out which classpath it's using and whether it is a different?